# How can i make a relative path for my database to my "mainfolder" so i can run my project on another computer?

Tags: c#

I created a database, I put it into my bin/debug folder, I made the connection with |DataDirectory|, relative path, and when I try to open the project on another pc it freezes.

```
string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\estic.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

Comment: i just took the connection string from the database changed the C:\..\.. thing and placed it there , is not something complicated

Comment: This still requires having Sql Server installed. If you're just using the database with a traditional single-station desktop app, Sql Server (even LocalDB) is a **really bad choice**. As the name implies, it's a full **server**, with all that comes with: running in the background 24/7 using up lots of RAM. You'll do much better with an **in-process** database like Sqlite or even MS Access.

Comment: Also: `|DataDirectory|` in this situation likely maps to the same folder as the application. If you want to open the project on another computer, you need a copy of the database there on that computer. If you're really trying to share the same database between multiple workstations, you want a dedicated station running at least the **Express Edition** of Sql Server, and you change the connection string to point to that computer and DB such that you don't use `|DataDirectory|` at all.

Comment: I moved the main folder , with all the stuff in it on the other computer , and I ran the program with the .exe file from debug , normaly and it doesn't work.

Comment: When i run the same app on the main computer it works.

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER us the attachDbFilename is a connection string.  It is not needed.  Just remove the attach part of the connection string.  The database is already connected to the database and when the attach is performed the database has the pathname.  Often you get credential errors when using the attach because the mdf file is owned by the database and normal users do not have access to the mdf file directly.

Comment: I totally do not agree with Joel Coehorn answer.  SQL Server is 1000 times better than SQLite.  MS Access is the worse database to use because it either uses the Jet or ACE which are single user databases and cannot be shared.  SQL Server is designed to be used with very large databases and is multi-threaded.